# Why does specifying a formatter on an int.ToString() call result in an empty string if the int contains 0?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, tostring

This is a very simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int val = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());      // outputs: "0"
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("#,#")); // outputs: "" <-- what if I want "0"!?!?

        val = 1;

        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());      // outputs: "1"
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("#,#")); // outputs: "1"

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

There is a case where I have an int that contains a 0 value. I want this to appear as "0" but it's appearing as an empty string. Is it because 0 is the int's default value? Does the formatter assume that because it's default the output should be ""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 0, use `#,0`

`#` means optional
`0` means mandatory

You can read more here: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> The digit placeholder (#) is similar to the zero placeholder. It
>   defines the position of a digit within the resultant formatted string
>   and causes rounding after the decimal point. However, the digit
>   placeholder does not cause leading or trailing zeroes to be added to a
>   number where the original numeric value has no digit in the
>   appropriate position.
>   The digit placeholder has a side effect when converted a zero value to
>   a string. As the placeholder will not cause the creation of either
>   leading or trailing zeroes, when converting a zero value the resultant
>   string is empty.

[C# Number to String Conversion](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/csharpnumerictostring_2.aspx)